# How to set data in recyclerview from volley response liatner in kotlin?

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Hey there every one I really need some help. I want to set data in my recyclerview from my localhost database MySQL via volley. Here is my code and I dont know what it isn't working. can any one please help? I also want to know how can I use received data outside the response lister in kotlin. what do I have to do?? Thank you

val userlist = ArrayList()
val displaylist2= ArrayList()

val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

```
    val req = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, url, null,
        { response ->

            
            Toast.makeText(this, "$response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            

            try {
                Toast.makeText(this, "$response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               // var jason: JSONArray = response.getJSONArray("return_data")
                var jason: JSONArray = JSONArray("return_data")
                for (i in 0 until jason.length()) {
                    var jasonobj: JSONObject = jason.getJSONObject(i)
                    var id = jasonobj.getString("userid")
                    var typeid = jasonobj.getString("user_type_id")
                    var name = jasonobj.getString("name")
                    var cnic = jasonobj.getString("cnic")
                    var phone = jasonobj.getString("phone")
                    var address = jasonobj.getString("address")
                    // Toast.makeText(this, "your response is $hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    userlist(edituserdata(name, phone, cnic, address))
                    displaylist2.addAll(userlist)
                    val adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(null, displaylist2, 0)
                    EURV.adapter = adapter
                    EURV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                }
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }


        },
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "${error("failed")}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
    que.add(req)
```